# Scrapy - Priority next link than start_urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
    start_urls = [ 'url.x', 'url.y' ]

    def parse(self, response):
         next = response.css('path::attr(href)').extract()
         if next:
             next = response.urljoin(next)
             yield response.follow(next) # here
```

Here my question is it possible to scrape next link before `start_urls` because even if I use priority parameters `start_urls` will always be scraped first.

Comment: what do you mean next link? can you give more content please?

Comment: what I mean by next link it's for exemple I'm at page 1 and there is a link to page 2. I want to go page 2 before going to url.y

Comment: your spider will always start from the link in ```start_url```. Why don't you place the page 2 link, in ```start_url```? This way you start from page 2

Comment: yeah I would like to but for exemple I want the 5 first page in url.x and the 7 first pages of urls.y without knowing there URL. Is it possible to do it with csv file who contain all url instead of start_urls.

Comment: You can pass `priority=<int>` to `response.follow` to give higher priority to follow-up requests. But you cannot have complete request order control if you want concurrency, which is one of the main advantages of using Scrapy.